# Can't localize line error when compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

I'm getting an error when pushing to heroku when compiling assets...
I've revised every single CSS in order to localize any error but nothing...

The thing is
it's telling me the line of the compiled file, but I need to know the line number of the error before compiling... Any ideas of how can I fix this? Thanks!

The error when pushing:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
       I, [2014-06-27T11:43:08.802691 #1716]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_6b3b977d-af90-4ecf-9f85-03999c81089c/public/assets/application-ccf6af846f884c868c81901ada8cf44b.js
       rake aborted!
       Invalid CSS after "  color: #333;}": expected "}", was ""
       (in /tmp/build_6b3b977d-af90-4ecf-9f85-03999c81089c/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
       (sass):6836
```

Comment: The error is there, look for `color: #333;}` and see if there is not a syntax error around that.

Comment: I've searched for every #333 and I can't find an error!

Comment: It must be there, run the css files through a syntax checker.

Comment: Hey @Iceman, the error was not after color: #333, in fact, it was after a media query... but the syntax checker did the trick! Thanks man!